# Casting Back to a 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, reinterpret-cast

Given:

```
void foo(int[][3]);
int* bar();
```

And the information that `bar` returns an `int*` by `reinterpret_cast`ing from a 2-dimensional array (with sub-array size 3).

I want to map these together. I know that I can do: `foo(reinterpret_cast<int (*) [3]>(bar()))` But I'm not really certain what is meant by the `(*)`. Why can't I just do one of these?

1. `foo(reinterpret_cast<int* [3]>(bar()))`
2. `foo(reinterpret_cast<int[][3]>(bar()))`

Can someone explains what this mysterious syntax means and why I can't use either *1* or *2* instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo(reinterpret_cast<int* [3]>(bar()))
```

is not the same as

```
foo(reinterpret_cast<int (*) [3]>(bar()))
```

The former is casting `bar` to an array of 3 "`int` pointers".
The latter is casting `bar` to a pointer to an array of "3 `int`s". That's very different.

As to why you can't use `int[][3]` as a type in `reinterpret_cast`, I am not certain why that is the case. A language lawyer would be able to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

There is [the right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) for parsing C declarations:

> The "right-left" rule is a completely regular rule for deciphering C
>   declarations.  It can also be useful in creating them.
>
> First, symbols.  Read
>
> ```
> *     as "pointer to"         - always on the left side
> &     as "reference to"       - always on the left side
> []    as "array of"           - always on the right side
> ()    as "function returning" - always on the right side
> ```
>
> as you encounter them in the declaration.
>
> **STEP 1**
>
> Find the identifier.  This is your starting point.  Then say to yourself,
>   "identifier is."  You've started your declaration.
>
> **STEP 2**
>
> Look at the symbols on the right of the identifier.  If, say, you find "()"
>   there, then you know that this is the declaration for a function.  So you
>   would then have "identifier is function returning".  Or if you found a 
>   "[]" there, you would say "identifier is array of".  Continue right until
>   you run out of symbols *OR* hit a *right* parenthesis ")".  (If you hit a 
>   left parenthesis, that's the beginning of a () symbol, even if there
>   is stuff in between the parentheses.  More on that below.)
>
> **STEP 3**
>
> Look at the symbols to the left of the identifier.  If it is not one of our
>   symbols above (say, something like "int"), just say it.  Otherwise, translate
>   it into English using that table above.  Keep going left until you run out of
>   symbols *OR* hit a *left* parenthesis "(".
>
> Now repeat steps 2 and 3 until you've formed your declaration.

Comment: To me this would be a little more helpful if you could demonstrate the use of this rule on the: `int (*) [3]` in question.

Comment: @JonathanMee In `int(*p)[3]` `p` is a pointer to an array of 3 ints. In casts you don't need identifier `p`.